# Link to the exact line of a plain text file without using html

Tags: html, browser, text, plaintext

Let's say I have a plain text file (the log file output of a programme say) hosted on a website. We link to that file. People open it in their browser. Is there some way to link to an extact line in that file? similar to the `http://www.example.com/file.html#name` URL scheme? The trick is that this file cannot easily be converted to HTML, so I'm looking for a way to do it with URLs (to go in a `<a href=...` code).

I am pretty sure this isn't in any HTML spec (even though it's not a HTML file). I'm just looking for a hack. The only browsers that will be used are Firefox & Chrome/Chromium. A little unsupported feature hack of those browsers will do fine.

Comment: Why is it not possible to convert it to HTML, and be it just line by line and pack each line into an HTML tag with a DOM ID ? If it's plain text, it should be trivial, shouldn't it ?

Comment: you could write a browser extension that can read an url fragment like `#L123` and scroll to line 123, similar to the github blob api

Answer (score 1):

**In order to use hashtags, you would *have* to use HTML in your text file.** You could create some sort of wrapper page that would read that text file in, beautify it and allow much better user interaction.